# Visual studio 2015 Cant stop debugging, stop debugging button is disabled, Shif+F5 not working.How can i stop my project?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

Cant stop my project in visual studio 2015. stop debugging button is disabled also i cant close my application.[stop debugging button disables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYyXN.png)

[When i closing my application that message is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Bsh.png)

Comment: what about this issue? As you said that you couldn't stop debugging, please check that whether your process was crashed during debugging. Whether just the specific app has this issue? Not debugging your app, if you just run it directly using "start without debugging", how about the result? Please also enable the Exception settings, and make sure that your app has no Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I used some external methods from a system dll.

The code started to execute the external method but it never terminated and the whole thing stucked. I wasn't able to stop it, even in task manager. Every time the code called that problematic ext method, I had to restart my computer to stop it.

Try to find something like this, and disable the call. If you can stop the debugging after that, then it is the problem.

(If you want to know: It was the system32.dll and the problem was caused by a wrong HDD driver.)